# Orthonormal system close to Orthonormal basis is basis.

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

$\{e_n\}$ is an orthonormal basis in Hilbert space. $\{f_n\}$ is an orthonormal system in H, such that $\sum ^\infty_1 \| e_n - f_n \| < 1$. Prove that $\{f_n\}$ is a basis.

It looks natural to use projections here, but I don't understand how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is enough to show that if$<v,f_n> =0$ for all $n$, then $v=0$. Suppose that we have such a $v \neq 0$.

By the completeness of $\{e_n\}$ we have 
$$\|v\|^2 = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |<v,e_n>|^2 =  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |<v,e_n-f_n>|^2 \leq \|v\|^2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \|e_n-f_n\|^2 $$

which is a contradiction unless $v=0$ since $\sum ^\infty_1 \| e_n - f_n \| < 1$.